# How do I position one image above the other in notty when using a linux subsystem in Windows 10?

Tags: ocaml, tty

I want to use Notty, so I have been looking at the "basics" [repo](https://github.com/cedlemo/OCaml-Notty-introduction).

So I download `basics_wow.ml`:

```
open Notty
open Notty_unix

(*
 * ocamlbuild -pkg notty -pkg notty.unix basics_wow.native
 *)
let () =
let wow = I.string A.(fg lightred) "Wow!" in
I.(wow <-> (void 2 0 <|> wow))
|> Notty_unix.eol
|> Notty_unix.output_image
```

I put this into my terminal: `ocamlbuild -pkg notty -pkg notty.unix basics_wow.native`.
Then I try to run it: `./basics_wow.native`

But instead of getting Wow! above Wow! I get this:

[image: red Wow! and Wow! next to each other, instead of one on top]

How do I get Wow! above Wow! ?

Comment: By "on top of", do you mean "above"? Or rather, stacked vertically instead of horizontally? "On top of" means overlapping, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense for a terminal.

Comment: @glennsl sorry, I mean above.

Comment: Your code is working for me verbatim. Running the program is giving stacked `wow!`s. Is it possible there is some issue with the terminal  you're using?  What terminal and shell are you running it with?

Comment: @Shon that might be it... I am using Windows, with an Ubuntu subsystem, and I am using the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I bet that's it. I've used notty on Mac OS and Linux, and never had any trouble with the `<->` combinator.

Comment: You may want to try a different terminal in the ubuntu subsystem (if that's an option) and/or posting an issue on the Notty issue tracker. It sees like something that should either be supported or a limitation that is recorded somewhere (even if only on a closed issue).

Comment: @Shon just tried it on the VSCode terminal and it works... **facepalm** Should've tried that earlier. Going to submit an issue.

Comment: It's always easy to identify an expedient course for debugging in retrospect, but usually never apparent in prospect! :)

Comment: @kkeey I suggest editing the title of this question to specify "when using the Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10" and then answering your own question, noting that it doesn't currently seem possible, and post a link to the issue you opened! ;)

Comment: @Shon Done, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently does not seem to be possible. See [this issue](https://github.com/pqwy/notty/issues/30)